# I can not edit my radio button anymore when I set it by code

Tags: angular

I'm making a website and I'm trying to make my radio button selected before I use it. So, I'm using a view child for setting my radio button to checked. It works, but I can not change the state of the button afterwards.

I click on it but nothing happens.

How can I do it?

EDIT :
my bad, i need use checkbox insteed. I confused both

```
@ViewChild('right1') right1: ElementRef

EditRights(){
    this.right1.nativeElement.checked = true
}
```

Comment: why you don't use ngModel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using property-binding `checked` attribute of `radio button`

HTML:

```
<input type=checkbox name=gender [checked]=checkFlag>Male
<br>
<input name=gender type=checkbox [checked]=checkFlag>Female

<br/>
<button (click)="unCheckFunc()">Toggle Checkbox</button>
```

TS (app.component.ts)

```
export class AppComponent  {
  checkFlag = true;

  unCheckFunc() {
    this.checkFlag = !this.checkFlag;
  }
}
```

[stackblitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dgcx16?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Comment: i would check multiple radio button at the same time

Comment: @Guillaume Radio button are only used to check one at a time. Can you use checkbox instead?

Comment: i see, i'll try

Comment: @Guillaume I have edited the answer as well as the stackblitz demo using `checkbox`

Comment: Thanks this is my answer. I just update my code to change each radio to checkbox and it works.

Answer (score 1):

try to use ngModel ,this way you create two way data binding this mean when the proprty (stateValue) update this will reflect the the input control and viceversa

template

```
<label>
  On : <input name="state" type="radio" [(ngModel)]="stateValue" [value]="true"/>
</label>
<label >
  Off: <input name="state" type="radio" [(ngModel)]="stateValue" [value]="false"/> 
</label>
```

componenet

```
public stateValue = true;
```

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-amswe1)

**Updated** ⚡⚡

if you want to use checkbox then just create a property and use ngModel like this

```
<label>
is working <input type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="isWorking">
</label>

<label>
has a car <input type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="hasCar">
</label>
```

> foreach checkbox input you neet to create a a property

in case you want to bind multi checkbox or create a dynamic check box check this example

```
  public options = new Array(10); // number of checkbox  elements 
  public optionsValue = {}; // checkbox values
```

*template*

```
<label class="option-control" *ngFor="let o of options;let index = index">
  option {{indx}} <input type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="optionsValue[index]" >
</label>

<button (click)="optionsValue = {}">Rest  </button>
```

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-x2gnxs.)

Comment: But can i check multiple buttons ?

Comment: you can add as many as you want as the have defrent value `[value]="1"` ,`[value] ="null"` and string value like `value="m"` or `[value]="'m'"` and by the end the selected value will be sync to the property `stateValue` 

Comment: Thanks for the tips but i needed to use a checkbox and was using a radio input.

Comment: @Guillaume I have add some exapmle related to checkbox and use dynamic checkbox hope this will help 